# Remove all occurrences of string from beginning of a string

Tags: php

I need to remove all occurrences of "0" at the beginning of a string:

```
00000012322   //  i would like to get 12322
0011330322    //  i would like to get 11330322
```

How can i do that in PHP ?

Comment: You can do it like :- https://eval.in/876421  or `$str = ltrim($str, '0');`

Comment: Are your strings always numeric? Do you want them to still be strings afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) function of PHP:

```
ltrim('000000123220','0');
```

Comment: Sorry, for that, You can see that the timing is almost same. While i was writing the question you also given the answer.

Comment: Okay... What you want shall i delete the answer.

Comment: Brother... see the problem was just the timing... chill yr...enjoy... its just a matter of fraction of second. And i am glad that we both have the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hack it by forcing PHP to change it to number

```
$var = "00000012322";
echo $var+0;
//or
echo floatval($var);
```

I'd like to note that this will result in changing the type of your variable which might not be what you want! As others pointed out, `ltrim()` could do the trick. You could also use `strval()` to convert back to string, but that certainly is more costly than just ltrim... All depends on the usage.